# Why in the data array in onPreviewFrame is too big?

Tags: android, sockets, camera

I've write an application which streaming image from camera to other side over socket.

I make a simple test with the Take picture callback, and send data array to client like this:

```
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        PrintWriter outPrint = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(mOutputStream)), true);
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                mInputStream));
        new HHH().execute(data);
        try {
            // Send file size
            outPrint.println(String.valueOf(data.length));
            // Read command back
            String command = input.readLine();
            // Send byte[]
            mOutputStream.write(data);
            System.out.println("Sent image...");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

It's work ok, and the size of the data array about 10,000 => 20,000

Then I've try with the onPreviewFrame, but the data array is too big, it's about 400,000 and it's will be too slow when send over socket!

Can I resize that data? Or is there any another method like onPreviewFrame to take picture and streaming? Or can I make multi capture camera and send that image to client?

Thank you.

**EDIT**

I found a solution to decode the data[] to use as normal. Hope this help someone.

```
if (camera.getParameters().getPreviewFormat() == ImageFormat.NV21) {// NV21
                    // Convert to JPG
                    Size previewSize = camera.getParameters()
                            .getPreviewSize();
                    YuvImage yuvimage = new YuvImage(data,
                            ImageFormat.NV21, previewSize.width,
                            previewSize.height, null);
                    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    yuvimage.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0,
                            previewSize.width, previewSize.height), 50,
                            baos);
                    byte[] jdata = baos.toByteArray();
                        //Use the jdata as normal.
                }
```

Comment: Try to take a picture of 640x480 and normal quality, which is about 52kb, high quality and 2560x1920 is 931kb, on phone my camera.

Comment: I agree with your check, as I said if take picture is different with previewFrame. I found a solution to decode the data[] to jpeg image and will edit the question soon.